# USB-C microphone not recognized unless plugged in at startup on macOS

Tags: macos, microphone

My MacBook Pro 16-inch (Big Sur 11.4) no longer recognizes my USB-C microphone (a [Blue Yeti](https://www.bluemic.com/en-us/products/yeti/)) once the system is up and running when connected through an [Apple USB to USB-C adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter).

If I plug in the microphone before starting the system, then it is recognized. But I can no longer plug it in and out as the system is running.

The behavior is the same with the two microphones I've tried. I don't remember exactly when the problem started occurring. Maybe shortly after the latest point release of Big Sur.

I tried resetting the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is the connector type of your microphones (audio jack, USB, USB-C...)? What make and model?

Comment: Do you connect it through an adapter or directly to your Mac? Which is your Mac model? It would useful to know the make and model of your microphone, too.

Comment: It connects through a USB to USB-C adapter. My mac is a Mac Book Pro '16. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried with a different adapter? Could you shared the make and model of both your USB-to-USB-C adapter and your microphone?

Comment: The adapter is the standard Apple one. I don't have any other to try. I suspect the model of the microphone does not matter, since I've tried two microphone models. Still, my main microphone is a Blue Yeti. Thanks again!

Comment: Everything works fine now. Not sure what change triggered the fix.

Comment: Also tested a different microphone?

Comment: It was a fluke, it still does not work, only when rebooting.

Comment: It seems to work again now.